# Is stack-overflow.ga legitimate?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I was Googling for some programming-related question and ended up on some Stack Overflow clone with the URL `stack-overflow.ga`. I noticed because I wasn't logged in. Is this a legitimate page? I'm guessing it's fake. Should I report it somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: The site in question appears to reproduce the SO trade dress as well as the content, and calls itself "StackOverflow". This is clearly trying to gain from SO's reputation and engender confusion (and is also not a secure site - http rather than https)